Intermitent Login Failure; xf86OpenConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed
I'm working on a kernel build for an rPi and have started to have intermittent auto-login failures. Looking at the logs, the prevailing message is "xf86OpenConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: No such device or address".
Some background information on what I have currently: I have an auto-login drop-in that logs into root on bootup, and then have also modified my Xorg profile file (/etc/profile) to execute "startX" on login.

Expected behavior: on boot, auto-login to root and run “StartX” to open a new desktop window
Error condition: At times (yet to find a repeatable reason), the auto-login fails

Using the current VT (that appears as just a black screen) and pressing  to get the “login:” text to appear and then entering “root” to login results in the “VT_ACTIVATE failed” error
Additionally, if the auto-login has failed, opening a new VT (using alt-f2, alt-f3, etc.) and then logging in to “root” results in the expected behavior
Error condition happens on approx ~10%-15% of login (boot up) attempts



Searching around for reasons why this might be happening I found a few potential solutions but also wanted to post here for input while I continue testing and debugging. I'm still pretty new to the linux kernel so trying to learn and understand what all is going on the best I can.
One possible reason I found in another forum post is that executing "startX" from a different tty than what's currently logged in on can result in an error. The standard getty@tty1.service uses the default tty1, and everything else (as far as I have found) references tty0 (current tty) so I'm not seeing where something could be the issue there. The archlinux wiki states this as well, but I'm invoking the window manager via "startx" which is supposed to pass that information to Xorg.
Another potential was that I found a stackexchange thread saying that if nothing is currently using a tty, that there is no tty defined (by my reasoning what would happen early in boot) which would also cause an issue. I'm going to remove the "Type=simple" from the auto-login drop-in and test that. My guess/concern being that the "simple" type by definition isn't waiting for the other services to start first and that is why tty1 isn't available yet. My bootsplash service has a requires on tty0 so I'd expect something to be available but that doesn't rule out that there's a conflict. Basically, I'm wondering if there's a conflict some times on the availability of the tty and that's what's causing the issue.
Some of the files that I've modified that I think could but causing issues:
my cmdline.txt:
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait console=tty0 quiet loglevel=3 systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log_level=3 consoleblank=0 splash logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200

my autologin drop-in file:
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -f -- \\u' --skip-login --noissue --autologin root --noclear %I $TERM
Type=
Type=simple

my splash-screen service:
#startup service for splash screen
[Unit]
Description=FBV splash screen at boot
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=getty@tty0.service
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fbv -i /root/pydash_splash.png

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target

my xorg profile file:
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
        export PS1='# '
    else
        export PS1='$ '
    fi
fi

export EDITOR='/bin/vi'

# Source configuration files from /etc/profile.d
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        . $i
    fi
exec startx -- -nocursor
done
unset i


With some continued testing, I made various changes to different parameters in my startup sequence none of which made a difference. Continuing then to pare out any potential issues, I removed my splash-screen service and no longer have the issue. I'm still unsure whats causing/how the conflict is happening but I'll try adding possibly a "before" clause in the splash service to ensure there's no conflict with the login service. No answer/solution yet but I'll keep testing and post when I have one.
